# Ansible run script on all hosts, gather output and send once to an API

Tags: ansible

I have the following task set:

```
- name: Initialise inventory_data variable
  set_fact:
    inventory_data: ""

- name: Get Instance Inventory
  remote_user: me
  ansible.builtin.script: scripts/inventory.sh
  register: inventory
 
- name: Set inventory variable
  set_fact:
    inventory_data: "{{ inventory_data }} {{ inventory.stdout_lines  | join('\n')}}"

- name: Send to API
  remote_user: me
  ansible.builtin.uri:
    url: https://myapi.com/endpoint
    method: POST
    body: "{{ inventory_data }}"
    status_code: 200
```

The desired result is that i need to gather the results from inventory.sh and send them only once at the end of the run.

I've tried different variations, with run_once, delegate_to etc.. but i cannot seem to get this!

Edit:

I am trying to gather some data from my script which is ran on every host, however i wish to aggregate the results from all hosts, and send it once to an API.

Comment: Wait, what the heck are you trying to achieve? What is the main goal? And what is the content of the inventory.sh script... also, what is the actual problem here. Does is still send e.g. a 100 times? we cannot help you out like this.

Comment: Hello @KevinC added some more info, but the main issue is that the above play triggers an API call on each host. I wish to trigger one API call, with the aggregated result from my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if your play looks something like this:

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Initialise inventory_data variable
      set_fact:
        inventory_data: ""

    - name: Get Instance Inventory
      remote_user: me
      ansible.builtin.script: scripts/inventory.sh
      register: inventory

    - name: Set inventory variable
      set_fact:
        inventory_data: "{{ inventory_data }} {{ inventory.stdout_lines  | join('\n')}}"
```

It's not going to do you any good. Your `inventory.sh` script will run on each host, which will set the `inventory` variable for that host, and the subsequent task will append `inventory.stdout_lines` to `inventory_data` **for that host**. This won't collect the output from multiple hosts. You need to restructure your playbook.  First, run the inventory script on each host:

```
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Get Instance Inventory
      ansible.builtin.script: scripts/inventory.sh
      register: inventory
```

Then in a second play targeting localhost, build your merged inventory variable and send the data to the API:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: create merged inventory
      set_fact:
        inventory_data: "{{ inventory_data + hostvars[item].inventory.stdout }}"
      vars:
        inventory_data: ""
      loop: "{{ groups.all }}"

    - name: Send to API
      remote_user: me
      ansible.builtin.uri:
        url: https://myapi.com/endpoint
        method: POST
        body: "{{ inventory_data }}"
        status_code: 200
```

This way, (a) you build the `inventory_data` variable correctly and (b) you only make a single API call.

---

I've made a complete, runnable example of this solution available [here](https://github.com/larsks/so-example-75163240).

Comment: Thank you! This offers a complete solution, but also a great explanation into why. Much appreciated.